# Ejecutar función al cerrar modal

Tags: javascript, funciones

Tengo una ventana modal que se cierra con la tecla <kbd>ESC</kbd>, lo que quiero es que al cerrar la ventana me ejecute una función que me ponga el foco en un `textarea`. este es el código que tengo hasta el momento.

```
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which==27)
    {
        $("#ventana3").hide();

    }


});
```

Y el cambio de foco:

```
function fococoment(COMENTARIOS){
document.getElementById(COMENTARIOS).focus();
```

Comment: de que framework es ese modal? el modal lo creaste tu?

Comment: Has probado ya sea mandar llamar la función con el parámetro que ocupa o la línea donde está el `focus()` directamente después de tu línea de `hide()`?

Comment: Juank, lo cree yo mismo y Lixus ya probe con la linea del focus() y no se como llamar la funcion con el evento dentro de otra funcion. si puedes colocar un ejemplo te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Debes indicar el framework que usas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: No use ningún framework y ya lo soluciones, muchas gracias.

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta que consideres correcta; es la mejor forma de agradecer aquí.

Comment: Ya la marque pero debido a mi baja reputacion(nuevo), no cambia el voto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

veo que usas JQuery, lo unico que deberas hacer es poner el codigo de la siguiente manera despues de cerrar el modal y creando un retraso para que lo haga de la forma correcta.

```
$('#ventana).hide();

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#mitextarea').focus();
},250);
```

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias Jesus, a la perfección-

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que lo siguiente es mas acertado:

```
$("#miModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    // Aquí va el código a disparar en el evento
});
```

Esta respuesta se dió en Stackoverflow en inglés:
[Capture close event on Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298041/capture-close-event-on-bootstrap-modal)

Lo he probado en una aplicación asp.net mvc 5 con Bootstrap y jquery, funciona de maravilla. Espero les sirva como alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.which==27){
        $("#ventana3").hide(400, function(){ $(COMENTARIOS).focus(); });
    }
});
```

si usas jquery, el metodo `hide` tiene varias caracteristicas interesantes, una de ellas es que recibe varios argumentos para personalizar su funcionalidad.

puedes usar `$('#element').hide(velocidad, miFuncion)` donde:

- `velocidad`, es la velocidad a la que se escondera el elemento, puede ser 'slow', 'fast' o un numero entero, la velocidad por defecto es 400.
- `miFuncion`, es la funcion que se invocará cuando el elemento se esconda.

te dejo links hacia la documentacion de hide y a una pregunta en SO muy parecida a la tuya.
http://api.jquery.com/hide/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935778/jquery-onhide-event-handler